# python parallel execution of several class methods

Tags: python, parallel-processing, multiprocessing

I've created several customized classes to transform dataframes, as follows (version simplified):

```
class class1():
      def _init_(self, a):
          self.dataframe = a

      def __getitem__(self, key):
          return self.dataframe[key]

      def transform(self):
          self.dataframe = (some dataframe computations)
          return self.dataframe


class class2():
      def _init_(self, b):
          self.dataframe = b

      def __getitem__(self, key):
          return self.dataframe[key]

      def transform(self, arg0):
          self.dataframe = (some dataframe computations)
          return self.dataframe
```

what I want to do now is to execute these two classes methods in parallel. 
I suppose it should be something like :

```
import multiprocessing

df1 = class1(a)
pr1 = multiprocessing.Process(target=df1.transform)
df2 = class2(b)
pr1 = multiprocessing.Process(target=df2.transform, kwargs={'arg0' : x})
pr1.start()
pr2.start()
pr1.join()
pr2.join()
```

However, after I executing this code, and do

```
print df1.dataframe
print df2.dataframe
```

I observed that **no transformation had been done** at all. (Though according to the computation time, something did happe when called pr1.start() and pr2.start())

Does anyone know what might be the reason? And what will be the solution?

Thanks a lot :)

***P.s***  The next step will be 'merging df1.dataframe and df2.dataframe. So I'd also like to know whether I need another function *fun_wait_until_all_process_finished()*  and then do pd.merge((df1.dataframe,df2.dataframe))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my opinion, using the **[threading](https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html)** module is the best way to solve this.

For ease of use, you can use a [decorator](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0318/):

```
import threading

def threaded(fn):
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        threading.Thread(target=fn, args=args, kwargs=kwargs).start()
    return wrapper
```

After this is defined, add the decorator to functions/class methods you want to be threaded like this:

```
@threaded
def transform(self):
  self.dataframe = (some dataframe computations)
  return self.dataframe
```

Then just call the function, a thread will be created automatically:

```
c1 = class1(a)
c2 = class2(b)

c1.transform()
c2.transform()
```